# RecyclerView inside a RelativeLayout not scrolling in android 9 and above

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The above code works perfectly in in android 8 and lower devices but it is not scrolling in android 9 and even text above the RecyclerView is not clickable at all

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurentName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/drawable_margin"
        android:textColor="@color/sidemenutext"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wareHouseName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/drawable_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/sidemenutext"
        android:textSize="15sp" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ordRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/restaurentName" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try making your RecyclerView height to match_parent.

Comment: Set the height of your `RelativeLayout` to `match_parent`.